# map処理の記述について

Tags: javascript

例えば以下の様なコードを実行した際、期待する結果のようにするにはどのように記述すれば良いでしょうか。

**期待する結果:**

```
01:011:元気になる
02:022:元気になる
(3秒待機)
01:011:頑張る
02:022:頑張る
```

**現状の結果:**

```
01:011:元気になる
(3秒待機)
01:011:頑張る
(3秒待機)
02:022:元気になる
(3秒待機)
02:022:頑張る
```

**現状のコード:**

```js
const User = [
  { ID: "01",
    PASS: "011" },
  { ID: "02",
    PASS: "022" }
];

const Request = [
  '元気になる',
  '頑張る'
];

async function main() {
  Promise.all(User.map((MainScript)));
}

function MainScript({ ID,PASS }) {
  Request.map(function( Requests ) {
    console.log(ID + ":" + PASS + ":" + Requests);
    sleep(3000);
  });
}

function sleep(waitMsec) {
  var startMsec = new Date();
  while (new Date() - startMsec < waitMsec);
}
```

Comment: どういう環境が前提で、どういう目的でこのコードを書いたのでしょうか。JavaScriptとしては奇妙な点が複数あり、正しい回答がどんなものか判断し難いです。

Comment: たとえば、sleep() のようなことをするには、ブラウザとNode.jsとGogole Apps Script で別々の対応が必要です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そもそも map が不要に見えます。ブラウザで動く前提だとすると以下のようになるでしょうか。

```js
const user = [
  {id: "01", pass: "011"},
  {id: "02", pass: "022"}
];

const requests = [
  '元気になる', '頑張る'
];

async function main() {
  for (let r of requests) {
    for (let {id, pass} of user) {
      console.log(`${id}:${pass}:${r}`);
    }
    await sleep(3000);
  }
}

function sleep(waitMsec) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitMsec));
}

main();
```

Comment: GASを用いての運用を考えていました。持っている少ない知識の中から選んで書いた結果がmap処理だったので、このような粗雑なコードになっていましたが、回答頂けた方法でも動作することが確認出来ました。

Comment: GASでしたらawait sleep(300) のかわりに Utilities.sleep(3000) ですね。